# Using Regular Expressions to Efficiently Clean Input String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a FreeCodeCamp learner trying to use regular expressions in JavaScript to clean an input string by removing specific characters.

I've declared a regex variable and assigned it a pattern, but I'm having trouble integrating it into my `cleanInputString` function.

The existing code uses a loop to iterate through the string and create a new array, but I've been advised that using regular expressions might be more efficient.

This is the original code I'm trying to replace:

```js
function cleanInputString(str) {
  const strArray = str.split('');
  const cleanStrArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    if (!["+", "-", " "].includes(strArray[i])) {
      cleanStrArray.push(strArray[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my attempt using regular expressions:

```js
function cleanInputString(str) {
  const regex = /hello/;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
    if (!["+", "-", " "].includes) {
      regex.push
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling with integrating the regex into the loop and properly replacing the existing logic. Can someone guide me on how to use regular expressions efficiently in this context?

Comment: Can you please provide example of the input strings, and also expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might missunderstand what regex is used for.

Regex is a syntax to search for different patterns in a string.

In you case, you want to find the characters "+", "-" and " " and cut them out of the string. Therefore, you can create a Regex that will match with any of those characters `/[+,\-,\s]/g` and then, with the right function, you can replace every match with nothing:

```
function cleanInputString(str) {
  return str.replace(/[+,\-,\s]/g, "");
}
```